# Unresolved HTTP2 dependency in grpc-js for bidirectional RPCs

Tags: vue.js, rpc, grpc-node, grpc-web, grpc-js

So I'm creating a client for chatting application using grpc and vue-cli client.
My proto file looks like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package chat;
option go_package = "backend/proto";

message ChatMessage {
    string msg = 1;
}

service ChatService {
    rpc Chat(stream ChatMessage) returns (stream ChatMessage) {}
}
```

at first i tried creating static client side stubs by the following command:

```
$ protoc --proto_path=proto --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:frontend/src --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:frontend/src proto/chat.proto
```

however the `Chat` endpoint is not being generated in the chat_grcp_web_pb.js file.
I then turned to the dynamic way of generating the services from a proto file as defined in the Basics Tutorial [here](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/node/basics/)

But while compiling my vue client with `npm run serve` , it gives an error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                9:51:48 PM

This dependency was not found:

* http2 in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/server.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save http2
```

Sidenote: I already have http2 but apparently webpack isn't linking it so i ran the command suggested in the error above. But after that it gives 2 warnings and fails to compile:

```
 warning  in ./node_modules/http2/lib/protocol/index.js

Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

 warning  in ./node_modules/defaultable/defaultable.js

Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

My node version is 16.4.2 and npm version is 7.19.1, and my App.vue file looks like this:

```
import * as grpc from '@grpc/grpc-js'
import * as proto_loader from '@grpc/proto-loader'

var PROTO_PATH = __dirname + '../../../proto/chat.proto'
var package_definition = proto_loader.loadSync(
    PROTO_PATH,
    {keepCase: true,
     longs: String,
     enums: String,
     defaults: true,
     oneofs: true
    });
var proto_descriptor = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(package_definition);
var chat_service = proto_descriptor.chat_service;

new chat_service.ChatService(URL, grpc.credentials.createInsecure())
```

Any help to solve this issue would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `@grpc/grpc-js` library is only made to work in recent versions of Node.js (and Electron). The `http2` module is built in to Node.js, so if you don't have it, you're probably not running it on a supported platform.

If you are trying to use gRPC in a browser, you should be using [grpc-web](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web) instead.

Comment: I did use grpc-web but it doesnot generate the services for the bidirectional end points defined in proto files

Comment: Is the code generation command you used for grpc-web based on an example from somewhere?

Comment: yeap, as mentioned in the readme here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web